# Jenkins attaching local image in email

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am facing a problem in following scenario.

i have configured am email to be send after the job is succeed in Jenkins. In that email i am attaching local image to send it over email to other users, using html

The problem i am facing here is once the mail is in my outlook inbox i can download and see the embedded image on my machine but when i open the same email on different user's machine its not displaying image its showing "X" mark.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: can you share your job configuration so we can help?

Comment: Are you sending the same email to several recipients? One of these recipients can see and download the attached img but the others recipient can't see nor download the image?

Comment: @JRichardsz: No... no recipient can download the image from the email..Its not showing download image option as well to other recipients.

Comment: uhmmm. outlook & windows cannot be trusted. I suggest you try with gmail or another smtp. If problem is the same, we need to a deep review to your jenkins job.

Comment: @mbn217: Hey i am just using below html code in email content to attach image and sent email.. 

<html>
<body>
Hi,
<br>
<br>
BUILD STATUS : SUCCESS
<br>
<br>
<img alt="" src="localPathToImage/report.jpg"/>
<br>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @RaviCharolli: Did it went well for you? 
im also trying the same image element but the image was not included on the email

Answer (score 0):

OK , so assuming you are using a declarative pipeline (because im not sure if you are using pipeline or regular job), you can add this code to your post stage :

```
  post {

    always {

        echo 'I have finished'
        archiveArtifacts 'yourfile.html or any extension'

        emailext attachLog: true, 
        attachmentsPattern: '*.html', 
        body: 'Smoke Test.\n\nPlease see attachment for Report and build Logs', subject: 'DO NOT REPLY: JENKINS Build Server Notification [${BUILD_STATUS}]${JOB_NAME} Build #${BUILD_NUMBER}', to: 'example@example.com'
    }
```

if you attachment (in my case is yourfile.html) is in your root directory then *.html is good to pick it up, otherwise pass the absolute path to your attachment.
Note : that its better always to archive the artifacts or the files you are trying to use later in the build or in other builds.
Also, make sure you have email extension plugin: [Email extension plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/)